# Edit and run Mathematica notebook on remote from local machine

Tags: remote-access

I have a labtop and high performance desktop machine, and mathematica is installed in both of them.
I'm looking for the way to use mathematica with remote file and remote machine as if local machine.
I'm looking for the way to edit and run mathematica notebook in remote desktop machine from local laptop with, namely the way which realize following goal.

**Goal:**

1. Use mathematica interactive interface and see the execution results on laptop
2. mathematica notebook fies I wanna edit and run are on remote machine and calculation is performed with resource of remote machine

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ConnectToARemoteKernel.html ?

Comment: Thanks Alucard, but with this method, I think I will open and edit notebook file stored in  'local' machine. I would like to edit file which is stored in the "remote" pc

Comment: Why not just use Remote Desktop? Then just use something like Dropbox to pass files you want back from the remote machine to your home machine? No need to over complicate it.